# export Windows 10 task manager APP history to the txt file

Tags: windows-10, powershell, task-manager

The new windows 10 feature - app history is amazing but i can't get the details in text format, may be it can be done with powershell or other way?
[image: a screen of app history task manager window]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this is a dynamic list that updates every 30 days.

What's your use case for wanting to export this to a text file? 
Just curious.

All that being said.

There is no native PS cmdlet to do this, nor is there an easy .Net way to achieve this that I am aware of.

This requires digging / researching at how TM gets this data and from where, then determining how one could access it for the use case you are after.

So, the first place to look would be in the registry. If it is there as a key item, the that is you export target vs directly from TM. I can already tell you I've did that in the past and nothing relative to this is there.

The second step, if it were not there, is a debug effort to see what dlls were being called and the peering into those using the normal dev tools used for examining (an often decompile effort) dlls. There are tools like reflector (from Red-Gate software) and others that can do this, but mainly a .Net dll decompiler. I've used such tools in my dev career, but have not done so for this sort of thing.